# How to hide all controls in fabric JS, and it should be look like svg

Tags: fabricjs

I need to hide all controls of fabric js when we click on fabric canvas ie: no move object or scale or anything , that canvas should be feel like a static webpage. your help will be apricated :)  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is actually set property

```
hasControls: false
```

More [here](http://fabricjs.com/controls-customization).

Comment: If you want it to look as an image, just disable selectable and evented, more in docs (see link in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to do it

1. Using class with pointer-events none to canvas element or canvas
   container and adding/removing that class when you want to enable or
   disable the events.

```
.disable-pointer-events{  pointer-events:none;}
```

2. Using Object/Canvas class methods/properties to control selectable and cursor properties.

```
function enableStatic(){
   fabric.Object.prototype.selectable = false;
   fabric.Object.prototype.hoverCursor = "default";
}
```

or

```
 canvas.forEachObject((ob) => {
    ob.selectable = false;
    ob.hoverCursor="default";
 });
```

Here is the working demo for option 2
https://codepen.io/ad121/pen/MWGgXbX

Comment: lol to solve this, I added a cover div with higher z index ,  I will try this and will update you.